# Is it harmless to luaL_unref twice?

Tags: lua, lua-api

When referencing a value like so:

```
lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

Is it harmless to unreference `ref` multiple times or will this cause problems? i.e. is it harmless to call `luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref)` multiple times for the code above or must there be only one `luaL_unref` call for each `luaL_ref` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be exactly one `luaL_unref`.
Lua saves unrefed indices in a linked list for later reusing by `luaL_ref`.
Unrefing the same index twice will lead to getting later this index twice from `luaL_ref`.  This means you will overwrite your data previously refed.
See https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_unref